# Dynamic Row Column display in PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have 3 tables as I mentioned in my logic.  No. of categories and no. of domains for each category are not fixed because they are managed from admin panel. So 3 columns per row are fix but how many rows will be there is not fixed.

I want to display categories and data of each category in following mentioned way.

[image: I want to display them in following way (as explained in below image.]

I am using below logic to achieve desired output it's giving different output.Please help to correct my logic so it can work like above example.

```
<?php
$str_query_select = "SELECT d.domainpkid,d.domainname,c.categorytitle,dc.categorypkid FROM tr_domainname_category dc ";
$str_query_select .= "LEFT JOIN t_domainname d ON dc.domainpkid=d.domainpkid ";
$str_query_select .= "LEFT JOIN t_domainname_category c ON dc.categorypkid=c.categorypkid ";
$str_query_select .= "WHERE c.visible='YES' AND d.visible='YES' ORDER BY c.categorytitle,d.domainname ";
$rs_cat_list = GetRecordSet($str_query_select);

if (!$rs_cat_list->eof()) { // Check if recordset is not empty
$int_cnt = 0; // Used to make new row
$int_cat_pkid = 0; // Used to validate categorypkid
    while (!$rs_cat_list->eof()) { // loop starts
        if (($int_cnt % 3) == 0) { // To display 3 columns per row
        ?>
        <tr> 
        <?php } ?>
            <td width="250" align="left" valign="top">
            <?php
            if ($int_cat_pkid != $rs_cat_list->fields("categorypkid")) {
                $int_cat_pkid = $rs_cat_list->fields("categorypkid");
                print("<b>" . $rs_cat_list->fields("categorytitle") . "</b><br/>");
            }
            print($rs_cat_list->fields("domainname") . "<br/>");
            ?>
            </td>
            <?php
            $int_cnt++;
            $rs_cat_list->MoveNext();
            if (($int_cnt % 3) == 0) { // 
            ?>
        </tr>
            <?php
            }
        }
    }
    ?>
```

While below is output I am getting. Please help to resolve this issue.
[image]

Thank you in advance,
KRA

Comment: Your code is a bit messy and hard to read. I suggest you rewriting it in a bit better way and making variables understandable.

Comment: Can't make out much of your code, but it sounds you just want 3 lists, floated left with a width of 33%. So I would simplify the php and use html / css for the presentation.

Comment: I don't see anything that appears to specifically be wrong with the code (other than clarity). Are you ordering the SELECT by the categorypkid? Otherwise, if out of order, you will get duplicate category listings.

Comment: I just entered sql query that I am using. 

Also all data will be dynamic so no. of categories and no. of domains for each category are not fixed.

Comment: Please explain or show the current output of the code and indicate how that differs from your expected result.

Comment: Hello, I just added output image with my question. Please review and help if possible. Thanks,

Comment: Can you show a `print_r` of your `$rs_cat_list` ?

Comment: I have attached sample of output I am getting with my question. Please review.

Comment: hi, do you know the concept of separating logic from presentation? you could effectively present your data and format it using css

Answer (score 0):

Create an array of categories first:

```
$cat = array();
while (!$rs_cat_list->eof()) { // here is your while loop
  $cat[$rs_cat_list->fields("categorypkid")][] = $rs_cat_list->fields("domainname");
  $rs_cat_list->MoveNext();
}
```

Now use the **$cat** array to do the processing.

foreach($cat as $key=>$val) {
  //here you can put the above logic just use the $cat array to do the things
   if (($int_cnt % 3) == 0) { // To display 3 columns per row
        ?>
         
        
            
            ", $val);
            ?>

```
        if (($int_cnt % 3) == 0) { // 
        ?>
    </tr>
        <?php
        }
    }
```

}

Note: Please do changes according to your need.

Answer (score 0):

Use just 1 row with 3 columns;

Print normal `<div>` with a fixed size for each item in category.